# Trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 and make it dual boot alongside Windows 10, both legacy mode

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, bios

Brand & model: Acer Aspire E 15 E5-575-33BM
Current OS: Windows Home
Motherboard: Acer Ironman_SK V1.25
Processor: Intel Core i3-7100U
Bios: Insyde Corp. V1.25

I downloaded [this iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.10/ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso) and I'm trying to follow [these instructions](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot.html).

This is the first screen shown:
[image]

Then I'm running into two situations:

1. it shows this error:
   [image]
2. If I do nothing and let it continue it shows all the screens depicted in step 5 (legacy BIOS System) until the one with the instructions for creating the partition for Linux, only instead of showing 'free space' like in this picture
   [image]

it actually shows *unusable partition* (this is the disk space I created by shrinking **C:** in previous steps).

I don't know if I did it right but I tried disabling TPM but it didn't work. I also tried setting `acpi=off`, `nolapic` and `nomodeset` in this screen to no avail:
[image]

I'm not a Linux expert, I would very much prefer to install Linux in BIOS/legacy mode since that's how I'm booting Windows right now, instead of reinstalling Windows to make it UEFI.

Thanks for the help

**UPDATE**:

Current partition state:
[image]

Comment: Linux requires a disk to be partitioned in order for it to be installed. That being the case you'll want to make sure you make a separate partition in a compatible format for Ubuntu.

Comment: @JoshMcMullin - Not true: the Ubuntu installer can create partitions during the installation process. However I suspect the disc has been formatted as MBR, so there are no more partitions available. If `/dev/sda3` is not needed (it seems too small to be relevant), it could be deleted, allowing a partition to be created in the 21GB free space.

Comment: @AFH; so you think it's because of the partition limit for MBR? so I should delete some of the partitions? AFAIK I can create up to four partitions on a basic disk using MBR: either four primary partitions, or three primary and one extended. BTW, the picture I posted is not my machine, it's the one in the tutorial. I updated the question with my current partition state. Finally, any thoughts on the first error screen? thanx

Comment: Is it possible that you have created 4 primary drives, and so do not have a spare primary so you can't create an extended and then logical partitions? Been a long time since I've done partitioning in Windows (as in, Win2k era)....

Comment: also `gparted` should be on the Ubuntu live disc, I'd recommend looking at things with that vs. the windows disk utility.

Comment: MBR´s partition limit was indeed the problem, I just [deleted one of the recovery partitions (the one that was not active)](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/96389-why-two-recovery-partitions.html) thanks to NavyLCDR there and voilà, problem solved. It still showed the first error screen, but then it let me choose the freed space for installation. after installation I can successfully choose what OS to boot from, thank you all

Comment: Glad it's solved. Because of the partition limit, you won't be able to create a swap partition, but you can use a [swap file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_a_swap_file.3F), though you won't be able to hibernate.